# How to specify class dynamically in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

So normal class methods and object creation goes like this...

```
$obj = new Class();
$obj2 = Class::someMethod();
```

Can I instantiate "class" dynamically? How? I want to do something like...

```
$class = "Class";
$obj = new $class?;
$obj2 = $class?::someMethod();
```

Comment: Have you tried? It should work (without the question mark of course).

Comment: Haha, I never tried, good that it's this easy :)

Comment: and what does "dynamic" mean? do u want to load a class dynamically from an external file automatically? that's called autoloading.

Comment: @stillstanding: I'd say the OP means to define the class name on runtime.

Comment: @Felix Kling yep that's what I meant.

Comment: By specify I thought you meant declare, which almost had me vomiting all over this page. Just to save anyone painful flashbacks, use the term instantiate instead. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$class = "Class";
$obj = new $class; // works
$obj2 = $class::someMethod(); // works as of PHP 5.3

// if you don't have PHP 5.3 and want to use the ladder:
$obj2 = call_user_func(array($class, 'someMethod'));
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work **without the** `?` in `$obj = new $class?`.